# Add a custom attribute to the main div of a node only on teaser view mode

Tags: 7, theming

I want to add a custom attribute to the main div of a node only on teaser view mode.
e-g

```
<div class="node" tarbot="left"> </div>
```

I need to add **tarbot** attribute to the main div of a node to apply a JS function. I want to affect only teaser view mode with my Function, not Full content display.

Comment: Is it custom field or any entity field?

Comment: You should be able to add custom attributes via `#attributes` key in the build array before it is sent for rendering.

Comment: @Kevin How I can. could you provide me a format or context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use preprocess function to change OR add an attribute to our node main div.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables){

  // Array of aatributes which we want to pass to the node div.
  $attr_array = ['tarbot' => 'value']; 

  // Condition for teaser format.
  if ($variables['teaser'] == TRUE) { 

    $variables['attributes_array'] = $attr_array;   
  }
}
```

by using this function we will get our node div in this form

```
<div class="node" tarbot="value"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `{THEMENAME}.theme` file(d8) or `template.php` file(d7) under your theme, you can use `template_preprocess_node` function and add the extra attributes to node by checking the view mode.

Thanks